# Random files on AWS S3 d_uf

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

i am working with AWS S3 for the first time using the AWS Mobile HUD.

Somehow my S3 bucket is full with (literally 1000's of files) that i cannot access (due to policy) with random d_uf,... names.

Any idea what these could be?

I am only using AWS for profile picture storage on my social network app written in Swift.

I create a folder and file for each user /AWSID/profilePicture/...jpg

The random files appear at root of my bucket.

[image]

Comment: Are you the admin? Can't you change the policy and inspect the files?

Comment: @Alistra that is a lovely idea! i will try this :)

Comment: @Alistra brilliant! i know what it is, it is logfiles from every single get / post to S3. now i just need to figure out how to stop this nonesense :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the following documentation for s3 access logging https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html . Now logging is enabled for this bucket you can disable using the following steps

1. Log into your AWS console
2. select the S3 service
3. select your bucket
4. select the `properties`tab
5. click the logging box
6. Click disable

[image: Step 5]
[image: Step 6]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make the screenshot and giving clear instructions :) This was the solution